# Prototype code to jQuery ( bind(this) vs closures )

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

Mornin' all.

I'm rewriting a prototype code to a JQuery plugin and don't know how to handle this piece :

```
this.observers = events.map(function(name) {
   var handler = this["on" + name.].bind(this);
   this.element.observe(name, handler);
   return { name: name, handler: handler };
}.bind(this));
```

I ended up with :

```
this.observers = $.each(events , function(i, name) {
   var handler = "on"+name;
   $element.live({
      name: handler
   });
}
```

I'm totally wrong ?
I don't understand well prototype bind() purpose.

Thanks for help !

EDIT: The context of that is a plugin init() function where I attach "dynamically" events and their handler coded as private methods...

```
plugin.init = function() {

    // the plugin's final properties are the merged default and user-provided options (if any)
    plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

if (!plugin.observers) {
    var events = ("mouseover mouseout").split(" ");

    plugin.observers = $.map(events, $.proxy(function(name) {
        var handler = $.proxy(this['on' + name], this);
        $element.bind(name, handler);
        return { name: name, handler: handler };
    }, this));

}
console.log(plugin.observers);
}
```

Comment: Prototype's Function.bind() is analog to jQuery.proxy(), both closely match ECMAScript 5 Function.bind() but the difference is in the function signature. The purpose of bind is to return a function where `this` is bound to a specific object.

Answer (score 1):

as for the Prototype-to-jQuery translation (read my above explanation on bind/proxy first), this should closely match the snippet above:

```
this.observers = $.map(events, $.proxy(function(name) {
  var handler = $.proxy(this['on' + name], this);
  this.element.bind(name, handler);
  return { name: name, handler: handler };
}, this));
```

I'm assuming from the Prototype snippet that:

- `this` is a Prototype Class or a plain JS object that is the current context.
- `this.element` is a reference to a DOM element, and in the jQuery case a jQuery-wrapped DOM element.
- `onclick, onfocus` and similar possible callbacks are methods in the `this` context.

Without further context on how your code works or which piece of a Prototype plugin you are trying to rewrite this is as much as I can help you (which I hope is enough).

Comment: Thanks for this snippet... Need to eat it! I don't understand everything... after calling it, doing a console.log(this.observers) returns  an array (which I missed when i looked for the equivalent of prototype map), but handler is "undefined"

Comment: btw @gonchuki, about your assumptions, pls see my second EDIT above ;)

Comment: and you sure that the same object that hosts the `init` function also has a `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`? this is a tricky part on the naming of the callbacks on the original prototype code.